# Target um elemento <ul>l com class="menus" excluindo a demais, somente um por vez

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.heading-list').bind('click',function(){
    $('.list').children().css({ 'display': 'block' });

  })


   $('.heading-list').bind('dblclick',function(){
    $('.list').children().css({ 'display': 'none' });      

   })  
});
```

---

Quero que quando com clickar no titulo, apenas a lista child daquele titulo e as outras listas não sejam chamadas tbm para explicar melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/FernandoSouza/67z3y1nr/#

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar `$(this).next('.list')`  para encontrar o elemento certo.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.heading-list').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.list').children().toggle();
  });
});
```

**Exemplo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/ckwgx3bm/)**

Comment: Parece que isso funciona melhor.Isso resolve perfeitamente o problema. Obrigado mano!!! :)